# Finding best (or worst) synergizing champions in LoL pro games using R

Tags: r

I have some data that looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ay13c.png

These will be pro league of legends matches once they occur over the course of the next few months. I filled out a few as examples.

Rows 6-10 are champions that each team banned. Rows 11-15 are champions that each team picked.

Each week has about 10 games and there are 9 weeks.

The B and R at the top are Blue (side) and Red (side) in the game. Blue side always gets first choice of champion and red side always gets last choice.

I want to find the best (or worst) synergizing champions

To clarify what I mean by this, in my screenshot the team with Brand and Yuumi won both times while the team with Aurelion Sol and Azir lost both times.

Optimally, I want to know how many times a 2, 3, 4, or 5 characters were picked and the corresponding winrate.

Edit: I am not sure exactly how the data needs to look in R because I have never done this before, but I made two different versions of inputting it below.

```
LoLGames <- matrix(c('W','Annie','Ezreal','Yuumi','Camille','Brand',
                     'L','Nasus', 'Aurelion Sol', 'Azir', 'Blitzcrank', 'Caitlyn',
                     'L','Nasus', 'Aurelion Sol', 'Blitzcrank', 'Ezreal', 'Camille',
                     'W','Bard', 'Ashe', 'Yuumi', 'Kogmaw', 'Brand'),
                   ncol = 6, byrow = TRUE)
colnames(LoLGames) <- c("Result","Champ1","Champ2","Champ3","Champ4","Champ5")
rownames(LoLGames) <- c("Game1","Game2","Game3","Game4")
LoLGames <- as.table(LoLGames)

*Corresponding dput

structure(c("W", "L", "L", "W", "Annie", "Nasus", "Nasus", "Bard", 
"Ezreal", "Aurelion Sol", "Aurelion Sol", "Ashe", "Yuumi", "Azir", 
"Blitzcrank", "Yuumi", "Camille", "Blitzcrank", "Ezreal", "Kogmaw", 
"Brand", "Caitlyn", "Camille", "Brand"), .Dim = c(4L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("Game1", "Game2", "Game3", "Game4"), c("Result", "Champ1", 
    "Champ2", "Champ3", "Champ4", "Champ5")), class = "table")


Result <- c('W','L','L','W',NA)
G1W <- c('Annie','Ezreal','Yuumi','Camille','Brand')
G1L <- c('Nasus', 'Aurelion Sol', 'Blitzcrank', 'Ezreal', 'Camille')
G2L <- c('Nasus', 'Aurelion Sol', 'Blitzcrank', 'Ezreal', 'Camille')
G2W <- c('Bard', 'Ashe', 'Yuumi', 'Kogmaw', 'Brand')

LoLDf <- data.frame(Result, G1W, G1L, G2L, G2W)


*Corresponding dput

structure(list(Result = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, NA), .Label = c("L", 
"W"), class = "factor"), G1W = structure(c(1L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 2L
), .Label = c("Annie", "Brand", "Camille", "Ezreal", "Yuumi"), class = "factor"), 
    G1L = structure(c(5L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("Aurelion Sol", 
    "Blitzcrank", "Camille", "Ezreal", "Nasus"), class = "factor"), 
    G2L = structure(c(5L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("Aurelion Sol", 
    "Blitzcrank", "Camille", "Ezreal", "Nasus"), class = "factor"), 
    G2W = structure(c(2L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 3L), .Label = c("Ashe", 
    "Bard", "Brand", "Kogmaw", "Yuumi"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))
```

Comment: I already have a screenshot of the data, does it need to be a screenshot of the data in R? If so, I am not sure how it needs to be formatted to show team x vs team y in a table.

Comment: Presumably, you already have the data in R. If so, use `dput` and show the output in your edited question.

Comment: I input it the best I could think of how to do and added the input and output to the question.